# How to compare 2 revisions in PyCharm, without the in-between revisions being included

Tags: mercurial, pycharm

quick question I can't seem to find for the life of me: How do I compare 2 revisions in PyCharm without having the revisions in between the 2 being included in the compare?

I'm using bookmarks for features (since branches are for more long term uses, such as testing, development, etc). I code several features (in separate bookmarks) and push them. After sometime, I will go upstream and do code review. However, the multiple commits from the multiple bookmarks are combined, and when I try to do a compare I get code from different bookmarks polluting the comparison.

Example:

```
|
o         r10 - baseline
o \       r11 - feature B work
| o \     r12 - feature A work
| | o \   r13 - feature C work
| o | |   r14 - feature A work (complete)
```

I want to do a comparison between revision 14 and 10 to do code review on feature a, but when I do code from revisions 11, 12 and 13 are included in the compare.

This is infuriating because when I do decide the code is good and merge the bookmark into the baseline, upon commit I get a list of changes that show me the changes between the baseline and feature A, without the intervening revisions. I could simply use this, but I would rather not since an accidental 'enter' press can commit the code, I can't use other PyCharm tools since I'm 'stuck' in the commit review window and other reasons.

Comment: You don't show how actually the *graph* of your changes look like, but given your question, I assume it's a linear history for those changesets. Then you use mercurial wrongly. You should use a separate head, thus a divergent history, for each separate feature you work on, and try to test and not throw everything together in a single linear history. And only merge a feature into your main line accepted head when it has been approved.

Comment: Each feature is a separate bookmark and hence, divert from the baseline (from my understanding this is what mercurial does when there's 2 or more bookmarks and you've commit work to them, a new head is automatically created). The problem is that when I push code up to be reviewed, the history intertwines the revision numbers so that even though each feature is divergent, their revision numbers are mixed together and it looks like the above example. This is why I get the desired functionality when I merge the bookmark back in; I just want this functionality separate from the commit window.

Comment: In your edited example with the graph: `hg diff -r10:14` will give you the diff which consists of the linear history between r10 and r14, thus the changesets 12 and 14). So either pycharm does something weired, or your graph looks different. But make sure to give both, starting and end revision or your currently checked out revision is taken as one end.

Comment: I took a deeper look and it looks like I messed up somehow and had a bunch of bookmarks using the same head and others in their own separate heads, so it looks like it was user error. @planetmaker if you want to make an answer based on your commit I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookmarking a revision does not automatically create a new head - it just attaches a name to the given revision.

However, if you created a new anonymous head for each of your features and bookmarked that, thus creating a divergent history with your base revision r10 as common ancestor and all features based on that like in your graph shown,, you should be fine and get with `hg diff -r10:14` exactly the output you expect to get: the changes made by revisions 12 and 14.

If that is not the case, then either you created some form of more linear history (thus your graph looks different; maybe you didn't checkout the base revision r10 before starting to work on feature B and C) or PyCharm does something different. When asking for a diff, make sure to give both, starting and ending revision or mercurial will replace the latter with the currently checked-out one.